# Return previous folder in URL

Tags: html, url

If my path is "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/" how can I return to "http://www.example.com/folder1/"

I've tried

```
<a href="../">Back</a>
```

Which get me back to "http://www.example.com/" and not the previous folder. Any clue on how to do it ?

**EDIT**

I have a

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

in the head, could it be because it try to go down 1 folder from that base ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="..">Back</a>
```

Should work if you drop the trailing slash. Don't really know why it wouldn't work with it but if it's not working, try that...

**EDIT** Just tested and both versions worked for me in IE8 - what browser are you using to test it?

---

**Another Edit**

If you use a `<base>` tag, all relative hrefs will be relative the href attribute specified as the `<base>` (thats the point of it). If your base is the root of the site, like `http://www.example.com/`, links that try to step down a directory won't make any sense, since there's nowhere lower to go, and they will just point to the root directory. However, if the base *is* the root of the site, there's probably no point in having one at all, since this is, effectively, the default - it would only make a difference if you were working from a higher level directory.

If the base is not the root, but somewhere higher (like `http://www.example.com/somedirectory/`) there is a point in the base declaration, but you have to make a decision - something would have to be specified absolutely. So if you have done it because you want to refer to all your images as just `file.jpg` instead of `/somedirectory/file.jpg`, you either need to change your image references to the absolute `/somedirectory/file.jpg`, or have your 'navigation links' like the one shown in the question specified absolutely. You can't do both.

I would say (although I don't know much about the rest of your site and how it was built) that your best bet is to scrap the `<base>` in order to allow for relative navigation links, but the choice is yours...

Comment: Both versions work for me in Chrome, FF3, IE7 and IE8... There's obviously something else going on here - do a CTRL + F5 and make sure you have a current version of the page, in case your running on an old, cached version. It would do that if you had a leading slash, rather than a trailing one...?

Comment: Could a base href mess up that simple url ?? -- yeah I think it tries to go down 1 folder from the base href and not the current url ... How to fix that?

Comment: When you say 'base href', what exactly do you mean? Have you put a `<base>` element in your `<head>`? Is you code more complicated than the sample you've posted here? If so, post some more...